# How to verify my client certificate with the Root CA certificate in Azure API Management inbound policy?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-keyvault

I have to take my Root CA from Azure key vault inside the Azure APIM inbound policy and verify my requested client certificate inside the policy.
For this I have followed the link and able to get the certificate 
https://github.com/galiniliev/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/galin/AkvCert/examples/Look%20up%20Key%20Vault%20certificate%20using%20Managed%20Service%20Identity%20and%20call%20backend.policy.xml

But I am not able to validate the client certificate by using My Root CA that I have fetched from Azure key vault
Following is the values of Root CA that I am getting from Azure key vault
{"id":"https://newdev-keyvault.vault.azure.net/certificates/MyRootCA/bf34888e**********","kid":"https://newdev-keyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/MyRootCA/bf34888e*************","sid":"https://newdev-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyRootCA/bf34888**************","x5t":"gYbnPUooh4D5_ogrmWCEvfDjYXo","cer":"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","attributes":{"enabled":true,"nbf":1587025108,"exp":1902385108,"created":1587036499,"updated":1587036499,"recoveryLevel":"Recoverable+Purgeable"}}

Can anyone help me to verify the client certificates inside the Inbound policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate you obtain dynamically from AKV cannot be used at the moment to validate client certificate from request. The only way is to upload CA certificate to APIM and then call .Validate on request certificate. That will require you to export certificate from AKV and refresh it in APIM every time it changes.

Comment: is there any Microsoft document that can clear this is not possible yet?